# ‘I understand that the earth is round wrongly.’

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Jack O'Flaherty Wed 21:41 When you say that you misunderstood
> something, you are saying that you failed to understand something that
> is true. That means misunderstood that the earth is flat doesn't make
> sense. You might say I misunderstood that the earth is round. I
> thought it was flat.

First of all, ‘understood’ is a transitive verb and ‘that the earth is round’ is an object. ‘That the earth is round’ should be judged by a predicate. It’s not an intransitive verb. And the that-clause is not the same as in ‘I’m certain **that** the earth is round.’

‘I understood that the earth is round wrongly, I thought it was flat’. Does it mean that the earth is round but I misunderstood (understood wrongly) so I thought it was flat?

https://www.lexico.com/definition/misspell

For example, “I misspelt ‘siege’ as ‘seige.’”

‘Siege’ is an object and ‘misspelt’ is a transitive verb. I should spell ‘siege’ but I misspelt (spelt wrongly) so I spelt ‘seige.’

Comment: "I understood that ___ wrongly" doesn't sound native or fluent.  It would sound more natural to say "I wrongly thought that..."  *Wrongly* doesn't fit naturally with *understood* because *to understand* means something like to know, or to comprehend, or to grasp the nature of something.  But if you're wrong about something, then you actually don't understand it at all.

Comment: @stangdon Yes ‘I thought that the earth is round wrongly’ doesn’t it mean I thought that the earth is in another shape? People (except teacher Jack) say it means I thought that the earth is round. But I didn’t.

Comment: As @stangdon says, no native speaker would say "I thought that the earth was round wrongly", but the logical meaning is "I thought that the earth was round, and I was wrong to think so."

Comment: @Kate Bunting Then I thought why I did wrongly means I thought why I did also?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I mean, ‘I wrongly thought about that ‘ means ‘I thought about that, but I was wrong’?

Comment: Yes, it does mean that.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Then ‘I spell ‘A’ wrongly’ means ‘I spell ‘A’ but I’m wrong’?

Comment: If 'A' represents a word, to spell it wrongly is to spell it in an incorrect manner. This is a slightly different sense of _wrongly_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes that’s what I mean What’s the difference?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say "I spell [a word] but I'm wrong" - you would have to quote your incorrect version. "I wrongly spelled _siege_ as _seige_".

Comment: @Kate Bunting According to the previous conversation, if I called your name wrongly as ‘Kane,’ I called your name?

Comment: You might **spell my name wrongly as 'Kane'**, or **wrongly call me Kane instead of Kate**. The distinction I was trying to make earlier is that if you said the Earth was flat you would be **wrong to do so**, but if you misspell a word you spell it **in a wrong way**.

Comment: @Kate Bunting You mean: that I said that the Earth was flat in a wrong way and that I said your name in a wrong way are different?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131589/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-jennifer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to say that you misunderstood the shape of the earth using a transitive verb with that clause as an object, I suggest
"I mistakenly thought that the earth is flat."

*I misunderstood that the earth is flat.* doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think it makes me think differently. I used ‘misunderstand’ as ‘understand wrongly’ as ‘misspell’ as ‘spell wrongly’, hearing you’re using ‘misunderstand’ ‘understand mistakenly (but I didn’t use it as ~ mistakenly).’ But I’m afraid I’m wrong.

Comment: _Misunderstand_ means 'understand _someone's words_ wrongly'. You could say "I misunderstood him to say that the Earth is flat."

Comment: @Kate Bunting His name had been wrongly spelt. 

Does this mean his name had been spelt but the spelling isn’t right?
 If it’s correct, I finally understand.

Comment: Yes, of course that is what it means.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you.